# not writing all lines of output in a new file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am creating a file and I want to write all lines of write_line to my output.
With this could I have a new file but only with the last line of write_log not all the lines. I think I should have a for before written log and tell to write all, but i am so new with python and need help.
I am getting name / familtname / id by SOAP response. I want to print responses which are in lines, now i just see the last line not all the lines.

```
timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
file = open(CreateFile, 'w') 
write_line = str(name).strip() + ';' + familyname.strip() + ';' + str(id).strip() + ';' + timestamp
file.writelines(write_line + '\n') 


def CreateFile():#******************creating output log file*****
    today = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')
    NowTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())[11:19:]
    Nowtime_split = NowTime.split(':')
    timestamp=Nowtime_split[0]+Nowtime_split[1]+Nowtime_split[2]
    daystamp=today[0]+today[1]+today[2]
    filename = 'log' + '_' + daystamp + '_' + timestamp + '.csv'
    destfile = r'C:\Desktop' + str(filename)
    file = open(destfile, 'w') 
    file.close() 
    return(destfile)
CreateFile=CreateFile()
```

Comment: What I can assume is `CreateFile`, `name`, `familyname` and `id` are variables created by you, right ?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas : yes

Comment: @SaiSreenivas : Ok , so is there any way to have a file with current timestamp and adding forexample 10 lines in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a small case:

```
import datetime
timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
file = open('1.txt', 'w') 
for i in range(10):
    write_line ='try'+str(i)
    file.writelines(write_line + '\n') 
file.close()
```

`

Comment: is there any way to count written_logs and put it according to 20. i mean first counting lines of write_line and put it as a condition in range(10)? cause the number of lines are different.

Comment: i don not understand what '20' means? if you want get the number of line,you can try it with 'readlines()',sucn as 'fo = open("1.txt", "r")   a= fo.readlines()  number_line = len(a)'

Comment: sorry i meant 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want but I think the problem is because you're using `write` parameter to open the file and it's always replacing the previous text, so what you can do is replacing `write` with `append(a)`:

```
timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]

with open(CreateFile, 'a') as file:
    write_line = str(name).strip() + ';' + familyname.strip() + ';' +str(id).strip() + ';' + timestamp
    file.write(write_line + '\n')
```

I suggest you to use `with open...` in order to avoid closing the file opened and other futures errors

Comment: I updated my code, i added this code the problem of this code is : imagine my result of my first file has 4 lines this works fine. for the second file with forexample 5 lines i have 9 lines! consisting 4 lines of first file + 5 lines of second file. I just want to have 5 lines in second file.

Answer (score 1):

```py
lines = ['line1', 'line2', ...] # set of lines (list) you want to add in the current timestamp file
with open('current_timestampfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines("%s\n" % l for l in lines)
```